# CPU usage goes upto 75% while stream a 300 MB file using WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a wcf service that is used to download files. Its working alright (finally), but i can see that when it downloads the CPU usage goes around 75%.

Please advise

**Client Code**

```
FileTransferServiceClient obj = new FileTransferServiceClient();
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[16 * 1024];
CoverScanZipRequest req = new CoverScanZipRequest(
    new string[] { "1", "2" });

CoverScanZipResponse res = new CoverScanZipResponse();
res = obj.CoverScanZip(req);

int byteRead = res.CoverScanZipResult.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=CoverScans.zip");

Stream outStream = Response.OutputStream;
while (byteRead > 0)
{
    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
    byteRead = res.CoverScanZipResult.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
res.CoverScanZipResult.Close();
outStream.Close();
```

Comment: How high would you like it to be?

Comment: It is next to impossible to offer any advise without further details. Show us some code please.

Comment: Normally i would not like it to go beyond 40-50 %.

Comment: @Brain, Sorry for that. I have now added code that calls the web service. Please advise

Comment: Might it be that you read/write a lot of small chunks, say kB per kB. You could try if you CPU usage is reduced by reading/writing larger pieces.

Comment: @excel20-- Please can you throw some pointers on how i can do that

Comment: @Amit now that you have a code example: change the number in the constructor of the buffer. Try 512 * 1024. Other question: What't the type of CoverScanZipResponse.CoverScanZipResult

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
byteRead = res.CoverScanZipResult.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Are you taking uncomressed data, zipping it on the fly.  If so that is likely your problem.  Compressing data can be quite CPU intensive.  As a disagnostic test, try simply sending the raw data to the bowser and see if the CPU useage goes down.  If you are zipping on the fly and sending the data uncompressed reduces the CPU load you have 2 realistic options.

1. Make sure you have enough server infrastructure to do this.
2. Zip your files off line so they can be queued that way multiple people accessing the service at the same time will not kill the server.  You can then save the zip file in a temp folder and email the user a link  or similar when it has been processed.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the reply. I can confirm i am not doing any compression on the fly. All i m doing is reading a zip file of around 300MB from the disk and downloading it from client