# WCF Streamed Download - High CPU Utilization Hosted in IIS vs Console

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I've looked at a couple of seemingly related posts that don't offer a solution (or a solution that helps my situation):

[CPU usage goes upto 75% while stream a 300 MB file using WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608133/cpu-usage-goes-upto-75-while-stream-a-300-mb-file-using-wcf-service)

[High CPU load using WCF streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545660/high-cpu-load-using-wcf-streaming)

So I'm hoping someone out there can help.

I have put together a WCF Service using .NET 4.5 to facilitate the Uploading and Downloading of large files (hundreds of MBs to GBs.)

I am using the "Streamed" TransferMode on a BasicHttpBinding with no security.

Everything works fine, however, I have noticed a huge disparity in the CPU utilization of the service when hosted in IIS vs self-hosting it in a Console application.

In the Console application, the utilization is below 20%, once in IIS the utilization is over 80% - This is a single instance download.

The service is configured the same way in both scenarios and both are running on the same box.

My binding is configured like so:

```
<binding name="UnsecuredStreamBinding"
                 receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="53687091200" maxBufferSize="65536" /> <!--50GB-->
```

The service code is also very simple:

```
...
var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
var size = fileStream.Length;

var response = new DownloadResponse
    {
       FileStream = fileStream,
       Size = size,
    };

return response;
```

Where DownloadResponse is defined as a MessageContract.

I've done very little to alter the default IIS environment (IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2)
Logging/Diagnostics are turned off so aren't adding overhead.

This is my first foray into Web Service development, so I know there is a lot I don't know and I'm hoping that I'm missing something fairly simple that would account for the huge difference in CPU utilization that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured out what was happening...

Under the IIS section of the IIS 8.5 control panel there is a "Compression" feature.
In there, there are 2 options which are checked by default;

- Enable dynamic content compression
- Enable static content compression

It would appear that the "Dynamic Content Compression" was to blame, un-checking this option resulted in similar CPU utilization to that of the Console application.

When re-checking this option, you are actually warned that it can result in higher CPU utilization.